# How to use input value to range cursor pointer value with js or jquery

Tags: javascript

> ```
> Problem:Live changing of input value to range-input pointer [My test code pen is here!][1]
> ```

```
 Upper range input pointer to lower range input pointer ][2]
```

Please, I am trying for range to range calculator in bookshop project. This is for cash back $dollar.

```
  [1]: https://codepen.io/YanKyawMin/pen/dyPoXxK
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4c3IY.png
```

Comment: Please format your post properly and add your codes here. :)

Comment: Please format your post and include your expected output

Answer (score 0):

```
// assign input value to another input below i have triggered range_admin value just replace your range_user.oninput with this code.

  range_user.oninput = function () {
      user_value.innerHTML = "$ " + this.value;
      //console.log(user_value.innerHTML);
      range_admin = (user_value.innerHTML.split("$ ")[1]) - 10;
      range_admin01 = range_admin;
    //  console.log((user_value.innerHTML.split("$ ")[1]) - 10);
      admin_value.innerHTML = "$ " + range_admin;

     //trigger range admin slider  
      document.getElementById("range_admin").value = range_admin01;

    }
```